# State of Starman?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, tesla-roadster, end-of-life

If [Starman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elon_Musk%27s_Tesla_Roadster) had been human and not a dummy, what would their state be now? Preserved or decayed? Dried? Frozen?

Comment: A sealed suit would prevent total drying. But the suit is aging under intense UV radiation from the Sun and will leak sometimes.

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/7827/whats-the-typical-temperature-of-a-satellite-orbiting-the-earth May be relevant to answer the temperature question. Most likely, Starman is sub-zero. Additionally, all space suits have a non-zero leak rate so there is likely no atmosphere left inside the suit, no matter how sealed it was.